# Print Name in Text File using python Regular expression

Tags: python

I am looking for a name in a text file using python Regular expression.
Example: If I have a Name in the format like Brad Pitt or BRAD PITT in first 10 lines I want to print the name.
I am using the following code.

```
import re

import sys

name=[sys.argv[1]]

for line in name:

     n=re.match("([A-Z]\d[A-Z]\d)", line) 
print "Name = "+str(n)
```

can any one please help me with the Solution.

Comment: are you sure you want to use `regex` for this ,

Comment: What do you pass as argument to your script ?

Comment: hello @ Guillaume I will pass a text file(.txt)

Comment: hello @akash karothiya Do you have any other solution then regex let me know please

Comment: @BHARANIKR  check the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Test this [one](https://repl.it/DKaJ)

```
import re
import sys

# template content : TODO load from file or program args
name="Bratt PITT\nYour Name\nSimpleName\nWrong5Name\nThis is a Too complex Name"

for line in name.splitlines():
    n = re.match("^([A-Za-z\s]+)+$", line) 
    if(n):
        print "Name = " + str(n.group())
```